# error message when clicking on a hyperlink in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049) exact problem with Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 Ultimate with IE8 loaded.

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

But the fix is for earlier Windows and IE versions, I am wondering if there is a more graceful solution already devised for Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, solved it by setting default programs to IE8. <kbd>Start</kbd> -> Default programs.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong? http://screencast.com/t/YjQ3ZWVlYzk

Comment: Instead of clicking "Set your default programs", click the bottom link "Set program access and computer defaults". From there go to and select "custom" and select the appropriate programs and make sure to check the box on the right. "Allow access to this program"

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but this happened to my computer after trying to uninstall Google Chrome.  Reinstalling Chrome fixed the problem.

Chrome didn't have to be the default browser, it just had to be installed.